# Styling Another Element Based On CSS :Hover Element

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to fill a custom bullet point whenever the list item is hovered.

I have the custom bullet:

```
.navUl li ul li::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

I Have an hover effect to change the text color:

```
.navUl li ul li:hover {
    color: red;
  }
```

But I want to also change styling (fill background) of my custom bullet, so I've tried:

```
.navUl li ul li:hover > .navUl li ul li::before {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

[Reference to project in question](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/wvadVag)

Comment: are you using css or scss? i see in the codepen it is scss

Comment: Preferably SCSS, but doesn't really matter.

Comment: it matters..this can be done easily in scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

CSS

```
.navUl li ul li:hover {
     color: red;
}
 .navUl li ul li:hover:before {
     background-color: red;
}
```

SCSS

```
.navUl li ul li:hover {
    color: red;
    &:before{
         background-color: red;
    }
  }
```

Comment: i saw your scss code you might want to checkout the basics and use it correctly.Thanks